# How do i return back to the original window when a email verification link has been clicked in a different window

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

wanted to know if this is possible preferably with javascript or php

For example :

I have window1 with some code which sends a email verification out to the user.
The user opens up his email account in window2 and clicks on the verification link.
The link takes the user back to window1 which changes to a thank you for verifying your email page.

Dont want popups, when i say window its in terms of tabs or new windows opened by the user. If window1 is closed then the link will open up a new window, but if window1 is open and the user clicks the link it will back to window1 and load a new page.

Can anyone help me out ???

Comment: You can't, that's by design. Live with it and die with it. Email knows nothing about browser windows and browser windows knows nothing about email. It's the user who is in control and will open the link however it suits her or him.

Answer (score 1):

use the target attribute in your links.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

target="window1"